# Python: How to search in first column of nested loop?

Tags: python, list, search, nested

I have list like this:

```
[
    [1, 37, 79, 164, 155, 32, 87, 39, 113, 15, 18, 78, 175, 140, 200, 4, 160, 97, 191, 100, 91, 20, 69, 198, 196], 
    [2, 123, 134, 10, 141, 13, 12, 43, 47, 3, 177, 101, 179, 77, 182, 117, 116, 36, 103, 51, 154, 162, 128, 30], 
    [3, 48, 123, 134, 109, 41, 17, 159, 49, 136, 16, 130, 141, 29, 176, 2, 190, 66, 153, 157, 70, 114, 65, 173, 104, 194, 54]
]
```

I want to find index of list item in which a searched value is in first column.

Eg, if I search **2**, it should return me 1 as **2** is located in first column at index 1 of the list.

How can I achieve this in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> [i for i, row in enumerate(data) if row[0] == 2]
[1]
>>> data = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 4],
    [1, 3, 5],
    [2, 6, 8]
]
>>> [i for i, row in enumerate(data) if row[0] == 2]
[1, 3]
```

Comment: Can it be faster? For long list this solution wont be efficient.

Comment: @Sanjivani: I don't see why this isn't efficient - there's no way to find every match without going through each row in turn.

Comment: @Sanjivani Faster than just checking the first item of each list?

Comment: There will be only one matching sublist. If code does not return all matching items rather just first then also fine.

Comment: @Sanjivani Then just change to `next(i for i, row in enumerate(data) if row[0] == 2)`, it will stop at the first match.

Comment: @Sanjivani `next` can also give a default value if not found, `next((i for i, row in enumerate(data) if row[0] == 2), -1)`.